# Replace "Text Space" to 0A20 Hex string - PHP

Tags: php, string, replace

I have a little problem i don't know how i can replace "space text" to hex string (hex string need to be 0A20).

My code:

```
$body = $_POST['arbody'];
function strToHex($string){
    $hex='0x';
    $hex .= bin2hex($string);
    return $hex;
}


$hexessage = strToHex($body);
```

The "/n" return is 0D0A and i need to return 0A for /n.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Could you provide an example of test input, the output you're currently getting, and the output you want to get?

Comment: I edit the first post

Comment: Why do you expect that `\n` gives you `0xA200` ?

Comment: In what character set does A200 represent a newline? Are there other peculiar mappings you need, or could you just replace '0D0A' (ASCII for carriage return + line feed, the DOS/Windows convention for newlines) with 'A200' using str_replace?

Comment: Sorry for 0xA200 ... i need 0x0A20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got `0x0D0A` because the remote client is a Windows computer. Note that the [newline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) character(s) are different between UNIX like systems and Windows. While UNIX is using the `\n` (newline) character, Windows is using the sequence `\r\n` (carriage return, newline.)

Btw, this sequence was originated in times of typewriters. If you press the "Enter" button on a typewriter, the carriage will go back to the start of the line (carriage return) and then go downwards one line (newline).

What you are seeing is a Windows new line sequence. I still don't get why you expect `0xA200`...

Comment: Sorry... my mystake 0x0A20 i need

Comment: 0x20 is a space. Do you expect a whitespace right after newline?